# Redirect SSH user server side

Tags: ssh, users, sshd

I know that  I can create shortcuts for specific users/servers on the client side via `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but I would like to do something similar but on the server side.

That is, when I issue on the client:

```
 ssh pub@name.server.top
```

I am actually chrooted to

```
/home/jon/pub
```

on `name.server.top` where I will use sftp.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have seen examples as the  following:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match user pub
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Will also the following  work?

```
    ChrootDirectory /home/jon/pub
```

Is it possible to create the `pub` as a sort of virtual user? That is, the remote user logs as `pub` and  his public key is in `/home/jon/.ssh/authorized_keys`, so without the hassle of creating a separate `/home/pub/.ssh/authorized_keys` or the `/home/pub` directory at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in a virtual machine context: the SSH server is Cygwin (also VM host); the client is Arch Linux SSH (also VM guest).

I used the following script.
I am not chrooting so I don't need to copy any binaries in the shared folder, only to copy the public key. Anyway I think that, using the internal-sftp (not SSH), binary requirements should be reduced.

```
#!/bin/sh      

## Setup SFTP access on server side
## using an alias user and to a subdir of the aliased user home
## ------------------------------------------------------------


## Customise
## Shared path inside the aliased user home
sharedpath="/home/jon/pub"
## Aliased user name
altuser="pub"
## Path to the public key of aliased user
pubkey=~/.ssh/pub_rsa.pub


## Add aliased user to /etc/passwd
user=`grep ^$USER /etc/passwd`
txt="$altuser:`echo $user | cut -d: -f2-5`" 
txt="$txt:$sharedpath:`echo $user | cut -d: -f7`" 
echo  $txt>>/etc/passwd


## Set user rules in sshd_config
txt="Match User $altuser
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
"
echo "$txt" >>/etc/ssh/sshd_config

## Copy the public key in the shared folder 
mkdir -p "$sharedpath/.ssh"
cp  "$pubkey" "$sharedpath/.ssh/"


## Format sftp line
echo "You can now run on the client (adjust paths accordingly):" 
echo "sftp -i ${pubkey%.*} $altuser@name.server.top"
```

Answer (score 2):

If it would work, you should probably have:

- `ChrootDirectory /home/jon`
- the home dir of `pub` in `/etc/passwd` just set to `/pub`.

`/home/jon` must be owned by `root` and writable only by `root`.

You also need a working root dir with all you need in `/home/jon`, such as `bin` (for the shell), `lib` (shared libs), `etc` (passwd for uid-to-name conversion) and so on.

It is most likely not ChrootDirectory you're after.

You could instead try to create multiple entries in `/etc/passwd` with the "aliased" user names you wish with different home directories under /home/jon. You can assign the same numerical UID and GID as for the user `jon`.

I'm not sure the public key authentication will work satisfactorily, though. Try it and comment.

Comment: I basically implemented your ideas, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably (ab)use the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` option for fetching public keys from all home directories, although that seems a bit impractical.

As for chrooting, read attentively on `ChrootDirectory` there is lots of things you would need inside of the chroot for interactive sessions.